# playerdb.co API not returning anything, no errors, just leaves variable empty

Tags: c#, minecraft, dsharp+

I've been trying to access an API for my discord bot to convert the input from an argument in the discord command to a username.

For example, if I were to input the discord command `?bw Tiim` into discord, it would return an embed with my bedwars stats, and my username would display on there too.

Bot response to command currently:

[image: Bot response to command currently]

Bot response to command with variables:

[image: Bot response to command with variables]

The issue is I need to find the correct capitalization for the username, so let's say I run the command `?bw tiim` instead, where the "t" is lowercase, the bot would still need to check for my name so I'm trying to grab data from `https://playerdb.co/api/player/minecraft/<username>`, which displays player UUID, username with correct capitalization, and etc but when I try to call it with the following code it returns nothing, no errors at all. I'm relatively new to coding in C# so I spent around a day trying to figure out what was going on but I haven't even gotten an idea of what may be wrong.

**Code for Part of Command Calling API**

```
 //bw stats command
        [Command("bw")]
        [Aliases("bedwars")]
        [Description("Basic Bedwars Stats")]
        public async Task bedwarsStats(CommandContext ctx, string userIdInput)
        

        {

            ApiHelper.InitializeClient();
            var hypixel = new HypixelApi(BotConfig.apikey, 300);
            var playerNameGrabberAsync = await NameProcessor.getUserInfo(userIdInput).ConfigureAwait(false);
            
            {

                var playerUserName = playerNameGrabberAsync.username;
                var playerAvatar = playerNameGrabberAsync.avatar;
                var playerNameRequestASYNC = await hypixel.GetUserByPlayerNameAsync(userIdInput/*This would preferably be the playerUserName Variable but to make it work for now I'm using the input*/).ConfigureAwait(false);


// Stats Fetcher Cut Because Unnecessary right now, would normally fetch data using Hypixel.NET wrapper

                var bwstats = new DiscordEmbedBuilder
                {
                    Title = "`playerUserName`'s " + "Bedwars Stats",
                    Description = "Overall",
                    Thumbnail = new DiscordEmbedBuilder.EmbedThumbnail { Url = playerAvatar },
                    Color = DiscordColor.Purple,
                };
                bwstats.AddField("Level", "`" + Convert.ToString(bedwarsLevel) + "✫`", true);
                bwstats.AddField("Kills", "`" + Convert.ToString(bedwarsKills) + "`", true);
                bwstats.AddField("KDR", "`" + Convert.ToString(bedwarsKDR) + "`", true);
                bwstats.AddField("FKDR", "`" + Convert.ToString(fkdrOVERALL) + "`", true);
                bwstats.AddField("Final Kills", "`" + Convert.ToString(finalKillsBedwarsOverall) + "`", true);
                bwstats.AddField("Final Deaths", "`" + Convert.ToString(finalDeathsBedwarsOverall) + "`", true);
                bwstats.AddField("WLR", "`" + Convert.ToString(wlrOVERALL) + "`", true);
                bwstats.AddField("Wins", "`" + Convert.ToString(winsOverallBedwars) + "`", true);
                bwstats.AddField("Losses", "`" + Convert.ToString(lossesOverallBedwars) + "`", true);
                bwstats.AddField("BBLR", "`" + Convert.ToString(bblrOVERALL) + "`", true);
                bwstats.AddField("Beds Broken", "`" + Convert.ToString(bedsBrokenBedwars) + "`", true);
                bwstats.AddField("Beds Lost", "`" + Convert.ToString(bedsLostBedwars) + "`", true);
```

**ApiHelper.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace EQNX_Stats_Test
{
    public static class ApiHelper
    {
        public static HttpClient ApiClient { get; set; }
        public static void InitializeClient()
        {
            ApiClient = new HttpClient();
            ApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            ApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        }
    }
}
```

**NameProcessor.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace EQNX_Stats_Test
{
    public class NameProcessor
    {
        public static async Task<userInfoGrabber> getUserInfo(string userIdInput)
        {
                string apiurl = "https://playerdb.co/api/player/minecraft/" + userIdInput;

         
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await ApiHelper.ApiClient.GetAsync(apiurl))
                {
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                    userInfoGrabber user = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<userInfoGrabber>();
                  
                    Console.WriteLine($"API Status: {response.StatusCode}");
                    return user;
                    }
                    else
                {
                    throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
                }

                }    
            }
        }
    }
```

**userInfoGrabber.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
namespace EQNX_Stats_Test
{
    public class userInfoGrabber
    {
        public string username { get; set; }

        public string avatar { get; set; }

        public string id { get; set; }
    }
}
```